# Fourier series coefficent of $Y(2t+1)$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing, fourier-transform

Suppose the fourier series coefficient of Y(t) is Cn then what will be the
fourier series coefficint of Y(2t+1)?

My doubt regarding this is if we do first shifting and then scaling ans will be $e^{jnw}Cn $ 
but if we do first scaling and the shifting then it will be $e^{0.5jnw)}Cn$

why is my answer changing and what is the correct procedure?

Here both operation will give the same graph

[image]

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$x(t) \Leftrightarrow c_{n}$$
$$x(at) \Leftrightarrow c_{n}$$
On scaling operation Only the frequency will be scaled $a$ times i.e $\omega' \mapsto w.a $
$$x(t \pm t_{0}) \Leftrightarrow c_{n}\cdot e^{\pm j \, k\, \omega_{0}\, t_{0}}$$
operation wise:For $A.y(at \pm t_{0})$ 
$$y(t) \rightarrow A.y(t) \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{shifting} y(t \pm t_{0})  \underbrace{\rightarrow}_{scaling} y(at \pm t_{0})$$

Comment: why can't we do first scaling and then shifting in that case my result is changing its very difficult to write what i want to say

Comment: yes it will change because the plot of the signal will change , take any example like rect(t/8) then apply two different procedures , first scale then shift , then first shift then scale

Comment: if we take x(t)=rect(t/8) and  apply operation like x(2t+1) then it will not change if we do first scaling x(2{t+1/2}} and then shifting and other way first shifting like x(t+1) and then scaling x(2t+1) it will not change sir

Comment: take x(t)=rect(t/8) then do x(2t) then x(2t+1) this is our first operation, after that apply x(t+1) then x(2t+1) , what do you see ?

Comment: Yes i will get the same graph in both operation sir i wil upload the image

Comment: see now my Question i uploaded the image

Comment: No it won't be the same , x(at) means time compression and x(t+a) means time advance

Comment: **operation 1**: scaling makes time coordinate (-2,2) then shifting +1 makes (-3,1) \\ **Operation 2**: shifting first makes coordinate (-5,3) then scaling makes (-5/2,3/2) , does that makes sense ? @Rohit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61016/discussion-between-rohit-and-lelouch-d-light).